# Stress in "control" word

Tags: stress

I heard the "control" word (and other similar words) stress depends on whether it is a noun or a verb. But I can't find any proof to that. Is it really so?

Comment: I (native English speaker) pronounce them identically.

Comment: I (non-native speaker) have never heard anyone pronouncing it CONtrol

Comment: COntrol is the most popular pronunciation used for the computer key among Russian speakers. Interestingly enough the same word adopted in Russian for any other context is pronounced contrOl'.

Comment: @shuribot So true! (I am this Russian speaker :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examples of what you are talking about are: *import, export, present, contract, object, refund, increase, decrease*. All of them are nouns when the first syllable is stressed and verbs when the stress is on the second syllable. 
"Control" has only one stress as far as I know.

Comment: +1. There may be others like _control_ that have the same stress as verb and noun, but I can't think of any.

Comment: *delight*, *husband*, *issue*, *reply*

Comment: deLIGHT, HUSband, ISsue, rePLY in my vocabulary - and examples of verb/noun there?